# Listbox copy values property

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

Does a `ListBox` have a property that enables copying values from a `ListBox` directly with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> combination after selecting an item?

Comment: is the listbox in a form? You would probably need to edit the object, or use code or a linked cell to get values. How are the values being added to the listbox?

Comment: You can use`ListBox.SelectedItem` and then `ClipBoard_SetData clickedItem`

Answer (score 0):

While this functionality is not natively available for `MSForm.ListBox`, you can write a few functions that will do that task.
You will need to add `KeyDown` event to your listbox and check for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> combination.
I use another two functions:

- One returns selection from a certain column of a listbox (if you set `HasHeader` to `TRUE` it will ignore the first row)
- Another function puts the text from the listbox into clipboard

Notice that you have to know upfront from which column the data has to be copied. If it has to be dynamical, you can look into `MouseMove` event to find the cursos position and infer which column should be copied.
You also might have to add some library references to your project.

```
Private Sub List_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If Not ListChoice(List, 0, HasHeader) = vbNullString And KeyCode = 67 And Shift = 2 Then
    ClipText ListChoice(List, 0)
End If
End Sub

Public Function ListChoice(ByRef SourceList As MSForms.ListBox, _
                  Optional ByVal Column As Long = 0, _
                  Optional ByVal HasHeader As Boolean = False) As String
'This function returns value of a selected row in single-select list.
With SourceList
    If .ListIndex < 0 - HasHeader Then
        ListChoice = vbNullString
        Exit Function
    End If
    If IsNull(.List(.ListIndex, Column)) Then
        ListChoice = vbNullString
    Else
        ListChoice = .List(.ListIndex, Column)
    End If
End With
End Function
Public Function ClipText(ByVal MyText As String)
' This function accepts any text strings
' and puts them in the clipboard
Dim D As DataObject
Set D = New DataObject
With D
    .SetText MyText
    .PutInClipboard
End With
Set D = Nothing
End Function
```